# How to use apps-script to override a file with more than 10MB content?

Tags: file, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a drive folder with a few g-sheet files (each larger than 100MB).
I want to override the content of the oldest file with the content of the newest file.
And then trash all files but the oldest one.

[image]

I have two problems:

1. Exception in file "Code".
2. My content can be larger than 10MB.

Is it a dead end?

```
function deleteOldSheets() {
  var df = DriveApp.getFolderById("1haqAtxk7ZeXF9ayEbRFIf7yGi3KBu4S_");
  var arr = new Array();
  var files = df.getFiles();
  while( files.hasNext() ) {
    var f = files.next();
    arr.push( [ [ f.getId() ] , [ f.getLastUpdated() ] ] );
  }
    if (arr.length < 2){
    return;
  }  
  arr.sort( sortFunction );
  
  var mediaData = DriveApp.getFileById(arr[0][0]).getBlob().getDataAsString();
     DriveApp.getFileById(arr[arr.length-1][0]).setContent(mediaData);

  for( var i=0 ; i<arr.length-1 ; i++ ){
    DriveApp.getFileById( arr[i][0] ).setTrashed( true );
  }
};


function sortFunction( a , b ) {
  var aDate = new Date(a[1]);
  var bDate = new Date(b[1]);
  if ( aDate === bDate ) return 0;
  else if ( aDate < bDate ) return 1;
  else return -1;
};
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by  "a few g-sheet files (each larger than 100MB)". Google Sheets files have 0 MB.

Comment: You can’t compare dates that way they are not numbers. You can compare valueOf or getTime

Comment: @Cooper but it says: `new Date(f.getLastUpdated())`. What do you mean?

Comment: @Rubén not sure I understand your comment. see my screenshot..

Comment: Try Date().valueOf() refer to JavaScript reference

Comment: The screenshot just shows thumbnails and the filenames. What do you mean by "say 101 MB"? Who say that? Where?

Comment: @EladBenda - Cooper meant that you can't compare `new Date() === new Date()` in your sort function (that said, `new Date("2020-01-01") > new Date("2019-01-01")` is valid) as they are objects first and foremost (unless it was your intention to make an "always false" comparison). Although you can do maths on them directly, it is only possible due to operators calling `valueOf()` under the hood

Comment: What I don't understand is why docs bs on the 10Mb rule if you generate a 10Mb string and insert it with `setContent`, that works and creates an 18Mb file no problem (but I don't work with `DriveApp` much, maybe I missed something)

Comment: @Cooper thanks, but the sorting works somehow. My question is regarding overriding the content of the oldest file.

Comment: @Rubén These are my client's requirements: files can be more than 100MB size.

Comment: @EladBenda - btw, you don't need to repeat the comments for both people if they talk about the same thing :) Well, it works because the clause with `===` is not really relevant, as it is always `false`, the sort falls back to your `else if` clause, fails it, and matches the `else` clause, resulting in `-1`. Therefore, `aDate` and `bDate`, should they accidentally be equal, will be swapped *as if* `aDate` is greater than `bDate`. Swapping equal dates is *pragmatically* not a problem, but it is not a correct comparator function nonetheless. I mean, why not fix that while you are at it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223941/discussion-between-oleg-valter-and-elad-benda).

Comment: If your client stated that files could be more than 100MB size you should say that in the question it tha is relevant. Google Sheets files as well other Google Editor fiels doesn't consume storage quota so their size are reported as 0KB.

Comment: By the other hand if your files are Google Sheets spreadsheets, SpreadsheetApp and the corresponing methods should be used instead of DriveApp for appending the content of one file to another.